# I can't get example scenes to run with Manim

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I'm new to python (and coding in general) and I'm trying to get Manim to run on my Mac. I've been following the directions on http://bhowell4.com/manic-install-tutorial-for-mac/

I got to the point of trying to test the animations by running:

> `python3 extract_scene.py example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl`

Here is the error message I receive:

>

```
/Users/rdownie/animations/manim/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "extract_scene.py", line 163, in 
main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
python3 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

Or

```
python3 manim.py example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

If you install manim via pip (`pip install manimlib`) then:

```
manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

Comment: For the first two it gave me:

/Users/rdownie/animations/manim/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Media will be written to /Users/rdownie/animations/manim/output/. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.

   There are no scenes inside that module

Answer (score 0):

You need install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) first,

For MacOS, just open you **Terminal** and run

```sh
brew install ffmpeg
```

For Windows, follow this link to install ffmpeg https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows.

Comment: What the terminal gives me an error saying that it does not recognize brew as an internal  or external command.

Comment: @BoredComedy Brew is the package manager on MacOS, you need to follow this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows) to  install ffmpeg on Windows, this is mentioned on the README of Manim source code, you should follow [these steps](https://github.com/3b1b/manim#directly-windows) strictly.